# p5.js Loading lots of images in preload() results in slow performance compared to setup()

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making a side scroller and trying to load all of the different images for various states of my sprite (running / jumping / idle / etc.).

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
function create_animation_dict(){
    /*
    Loads all sprites and puts them into a dictionary of arrays of p5.js images
    */
    let img_dict = {};
    let state_counts = {'Dead': 17, 'Idle': 16, 'Jump': 16, 'Run': 11, 'Slide': 11, 'Walk': 13};
    let dir_prefix = './assets/santa/'

    for(key in state_counts){
        img_dict[key] = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < state_counts[key]; i++){
            const img_loc = dir_prefix + key + ' (' + (i + 1) + ').png';
            img_dict[key].push(loadImage(img_loc));
        }
    }
    console.log(img_dict);
    return img_dict;

}
```

**Summary of code:**

The files are named in the pattern: `path/to/santa/Run (1).png` and the dictionary `state_counts` refers to how many images there are for each sprite state.

I loop over the `state_counts` dictionary to call the `loadImage()` p5.js function on all of them.

**Problem**

When I run this code in the `preload()` function in `sketch.js` my program runs very slowly. When I move this code to `setup()` everything runs fine. I make no other changes aside from moving between `preload()` and `setup`. What could be causing this??

**Problem by the numbers**

```
# Produced by consonle.log(frameRate());
sketch.js:84 0.3703017959588576
sketch.js:84 1.1664528170186537
sketch.js:84 4.191114836855708
sketch.js:84 4.154549230995268
sketch.js:84 4.537205081853747
sketch.js:84 4.618937644759058
sketch.js:84 3.9093041432105173
sketch.js:84 4.844961241099279
sketch.js:84 4.859086491831907
sketch.js:84 3.8314176245415803
sketch.js:84 4.192872116770066
sketch.js:84 1.159151501104072
sketch.js:84 38.46153852904557 #THIS IS WHEN I CHANGE TABS AND COME BACK
sketch.js:84 82.64462775185976
sketch.js:84 48.543689346504706
sketch.js:84 16.207455439478935
sketch.js:84 58.47953197391736
sketch.js:84 59.523809583865045
sketch.js:84 51.813471541844784
sketch.js:84 71.9424459400119
sketch.js:84 59.523809583865045
sketch.js:84 57.47126432967235
sketch.js:84 64.51612911754046
sketch.js:84 59.17159767585282
sketch.js:84 54.644808754849514
sketch.js:84 62.111801211336854
sketch.js:84 63.69426756050796
```

**Code in sketch.js version 1**

```
let santa_images = {};
function preload(){
    santa_images = create_animation_dict();
}
```

**Code in sketch.js version 2**

```
let santa_images = {};
function setup(){
    santa_images = create_animation_dict();
}
```

**Additional Notes**

1. Testing locally on Google Chrome
2. If I change tabs and then come back, it runs normally vs. staying on the same tab from page load
3. Very, very surprisingly, runs fine on microsoft Edge

Needless to say, I'm baffled and have no idea why this small change would make a difference.

Comment: Can you please be more specific than saying it runs slowly? Do you mean it takes a long time to start up? Do you mean your frame rate is lower than what you expected?

Comment: @KevinWorkman precisely, frame rate is extremely low, I'll get some hard numbers on this in just a minute